# Flutter web app using Firebase is not launching on Chrome

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an existing Flutter project.

The project uses Firebase Cloud Messaging to receive push notifications.

The iOS app and the Android app are working fine, both receive push notifications.

Now I want to create a web app for the project.

In the Firebase console I have added a new app for the Flutter web app.

I have updated the web project index.html file adding the following script inside the body tag:

```
  <script type="module">

  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-app.js";
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-messaging.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-analytics.js";
  
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "A...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
```

The issue is that after launching the app using Chrome (web), the web app is launched, but only the launch screen, then it stops and the debugger shows following output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:54031/2qJSa8Ll6LY=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54031/2qJSa8Ll6LY=/ws

 Running with sound null safety 
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54031/2qJSa8Ll6LY=/ws
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Auto
WARNING: found an existing <meta name="viewport"> tag. Flutter Web uses its own viewport configuration for better compatibility with Flutter. This tag will be replaced.
001
002
005
Error: Assertion failed: file:///Users/modestovascofornas/Desarrollo/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.7.0/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:207:11
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3    assertFailed
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 207:18                  initializeApp
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 566:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 528:22                                         <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 566:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 639:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

I would like to know if I am doing something wrong and if there is something missing on the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would utilize this installation guide for configuring your firebase packages for Flutter web. This should resolve your issues if you format it as described.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web/